# Php not printing correct value when changing value from javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have an html page that submits a form through javascript.  Before submitting the form I change the value of a hidden tag which I then try to get in php but it doesn't work. It appears blank.

Here is the javascript

```
function remove(){



remove.value = 'true';


  document.newrow.submit() ;


}
```

The value for remove is set successfully however when I submit the form I get a blank value.

Here is the php code to retrieve the value.

```
$test = $_POST['remove'];


echo $test;
```

any idea why the value is blank?

Thanks

```
<form name = 'newrow' action = 'update.php' method = 'post'>


<input type='hidden' name='remove' id = 'remove' /><a href='javascript:remove()'><img src = 'images/delete.png' / ></a>
```

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say?

Comment: Can we have more source? For all we know, it's a GET form and `remove` is a DOM element that isn't even in it.

Comment: No I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
remove.value = 'true';
```

Is too ambigous. Try using `document.getElementById('remove').value`, assuming that the element has `remove` as its ID.

Comment: @user541597: are you sure that form gets submitted?

Comment: yes I get to the php page, and I get other values for other tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this

```
<input type='hidden' name='random' id='random' />
<input type='submit' name='enter' value="Enter" onclick="remove" />
```

function remove()
{
 document.getElementById("random").value='true';
}

//PHP part

```
if(isset($_POST['enter']))
{
   $ramdom=$_POST['random'];
}
```

The error probably is that you are submitting it twice

--Update for anchor tag

Here is what you're missing:

```
A link does not submit the form with input data, it just changes the url.
Submit the form.
Override the default <a> behavior (for example, using return false).

function random()  
{  
    document.getElementById("random").value = 'true';  
    document.getElementById("thisForm").submit();
    return false;
}
```

You can call it using:

```
<a href="" name="enter" onclick="return random();">Enter </a>
```

Comment: how am I submitting it twice? I'm actually submitting once through javascript only.

Comment: I'm using an anchor tag to submit with javascript not a submit button.

Comment: Anchor tab does not post data use a submit button and make it look like a anchor tab using stylesheet